# What happens if a PWA's cache name changes?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA and in the `sw.js` file, the cache name is set like:

`var cacheName = 'my-super-sweet-pwa-app8wfjawa89ja0';`

The `my-super-sweet-pwa` part can change though, so sometimes, in the current state, it's possible that the cache name could change, including after the PWA already is installed.

I am a bit confused as to how the cache actually functions. How would this affect things?

Answer (score 0):

Each [`Cache`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) instance in the Cache Storage API has a specific name. When you open a cache to perform a read or write operation, you need to specify the same name as you previously provided if you want access to the previously cached data.

If you open a cache using a brand new name that had never been used before, the cache will be empty, and you won't be able to `match()` anything in it. You can still write new `Response`s to an empty cache.

There's a helper method, [`caches.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/match), that will find a given `Request` in *any* cache, regardless of the cache name.

So that's the significance of cache names. But taking a step back, it sounds like you might have more fundamental questions about how to effectively use caches and how they come into play with the service worker lifecycle. I would recommend reading through [The Service Worker Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle) before you do anything else, as that will explain how these concepts relate to real-world scenarios.